# Append bytes to a content of nt:unstructured type of node in jcr

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I want to append some bytes in a already saved file in JCR .How can we do this ?
The file is stored in a nt:unstructured node in the JCR repo. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the Binary values are streamed, I don't think you have a choice other than to create a new Binary using the stream of the original plus the extra bytes you want to append. In other words, I know of no utility of built-in functionality, so you have to write this minimal code yourself.